# Is there a better implementation for SybaseDialect in Version 3.0 of NHibernate?

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, sap-ase, nhibernate-3

We have upgraded to NHibernate 3.0 with Fluent-NHibernate.

In version 2.1.2 we where able to use the SybaseDialect for ASE 12. In version 3.0 SybaseDialect for ASE 12 is not supported.

I reused the old Dialect from Nhib 2.1.2 and all is working.

What I wanted to ask since this one was removed as it was considered not a good implementation, is there a better one out there?

Since it's working I am not sure what improvements need be made but I thought I would ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the Dialect class from NHibernate v2.1.2 and created a `SybaseDialect.cs` and then in the Config file I reference it, this seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

This [blog post](http://iablog.sybase.com/paulley/2010/08/nhibernate-3-0-0-alpha-is-released/) has the scoop. Haven't tried upgrading so can't comment if the version 2.1.2 Sybase dialect with NHibernate 3.0 will perform any differently than using it with the NHibernate 2.1.2 version.